# cleanest & best way to handle custom error in scala with lesser match clauses

Tags: validation, scala, exception

I'm trying to find the best and cleanest way to handle custom errors in scala.

At present I've a common Global error object (my code looks similar to this):

```
sealed trait AppError {
  def message: String
}

object AppError {

  /* Cat Error Messages */
  case class CatNotFound(id: Long) extends AppError {
    val message = Messages("cat.not_found").format(id)
  }
  case class CatNotForUser(id: Long) extends AppError {
    val message = Messages("cat.not_for_user").format(id)
  }

}
```

Every method is returning `Either[<SomeValidType>, AppError]` (I'm sending error in right side) for example:

```
def getCatForUser(id: Long, user: User): Either[Boolean, AppError] = {
    CatService get(id) match {
      case None => CatNotFound(id)
      case Some(x) =>
        CatService isAccessibleByUser(x, user) match {
          case false => CatNotForUser(id)
          case true => true
        }
    }
  }
```

The method which is calling the validation/get part have a lot of nested `match` like this:

```
def something(id: Long, user: User) = {
  getCatForUser(id, user) match {
    case Left(b) =>
       anotherMethodReturnsEither(id) match {
         case Left(x) =>
            thereCanBeLotOfNesting(user) match {
              case Left(y) =>
                // do something or create another nesting call
              case Right(e) =>
                handleSomeHow(e)
            }
         case Right(e) =>
            handleSomeHow(e)
        }
    case Right(e) =>
      handleSomeHow(e)
  }
}

def handleSomeHow(e: AppError) = {
     e match {
        case CatNotFound(_) => NotFound(e.message)
        case CatNotForUser(_) => Unauthorized(e.message)
     }
}
```

In one project I was using `CustomExceptions` to handle such nesting/if else. In that case I was throwing errors which were propagated to the top where they can be handled together. **The code looks clean when we are using exceptions instead of errors.** But I think its a problem with exceptions when you are validating data & have a method like this that doesn't return anything but `throw Exception`:

```
def validateCatForUser(id: Long, user: User) = {
    CatService get(id) match {
      case None => throw CatNotFound(id)
      case Some(x) =>
        CatService isAccessibleByUser(x, user) match {
          case false => throw CatNotForUser(id)
          case true => // nothing can be returned as its validation
        }
    }
  }
```

and I'll use it like:

```
def something(id: Long, user: User) = {
  validateCatForUser(id, user)
  /*
   * here will be some logic after validation
   */
}
```

Still its clean and readable. So my question is what should I use to achieve a more readable code with less `match` clause having `Left() or Right()`. I was reading about scala validation and found http://blog.lunatech.com/2012/03/02/validation-scala but scala 'Validation' also returns `ValidationNEL[String, <some valid type>]` which doesn't reduce `match` clause. The best way to handle custom errors, in my situation, according to you would be?

Comment: for comprehensions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` comprehensions really help with the readability/nesting issue when working with `Either`.  You can use `left` and `right` to project the `Eithers` and yield an `Either` that will collect the error:

```
val x = Left(5) : Either[Int, String]
val y = Right("error") : Either[Int, String]
val z = Right("error") : Either[Int, String]

for {
   xval <- x.left
   yval <- y.left
   zval <- z.left
 } yield zval
```

Your nested version could be made much cleaner using this syntax.  It might look something like this:

```
def something(id: Long, user: User) = {
    for {
        cat <- getCatForUser(id, user).left
        otherValues <- anotherMethodReturnsEither(id).left
        noNesting <- thereCanBeLotOfNesting(user).left
    } yield noNesting
} match {
    case Left(value) => // do something
    case Right(e) => handleSomeHow(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to Scalaz's `\/` (I call it 'Scalaz Either', or 'Or') and move your 'happy path' to the right side.

`\/` is right-side biased which allows you to use it in for-comprehensions.  You can write:

```
for {
  resA <- computeA()
  resB <- computeB(resA)
} yield resB
```

where `computeX` return `\/[Error, X]`.

Comment: They thanks. Seems like a good solution when an `Error` or `MyObject` is returned. But I've lot of services with lot of computations functions which are returning `Either[<success>, AppError]`. So does this mean that wherever I'm handling `Either`, a for loop will be present? This will mean that my every handling def would be having a for-comprehension loop.